Is it correct to say "I was taking a photo of my son when my daughter got in the camera's view"?
If I am watching TV and someone standing in front of me, I say "You are blocking my view of the TV".
Now I am taking a photo or a video and someone jumps into the area in front of the camera.
Now "my view" will be the camera's view
Is it correct to say "I was taking a photo of my son when my daughter got in the camera's view of him"?
Or maybe "I was taking a photo of my son when my daughter got in the camera's sight of him"?

got in frame is I think the idiomatic way to say what you want.

When someone jumps in front of your camera and blocks your [camera] shot, it is quite normal to say, You're blocking my shot.  You could even stick with your TV comment and say, You're blocking my view.  It makes perfect sense contextually.

no, camera's view of him is very awkward.

@EllieK, "block the shot" is a little extreme because she might just stand next to him but I just want to take a photo of him only not her.

@Tom - Ahh!  What you are describing is someone getting into the picture, not in the way of the picture.  The slang term photobomb is one way to describe the situation.  As a speaker of AmE, I would say, I was taking a photo of my son and my daughter got in the picture.  I wouldn't mention the camera.  Context will clarify that you are talking about the shot and not the final photograph.

If you're explaining to someone, after the fact, that one of your children either made it impossible to take a snapshot, or somehow ruined it:

As I was taking the picture,  my son | daughter got in the way.
Just as I took the shot, my son | daughter stepped in front of me.

If you're a film director explaining to a producer why you need to do the shot over:

As we were filming the scene where the sheriff and the outlaw are facing each other down on Main Street, an Amazon delivery truck entered the frame.


Yes, got in the way.

A chatbox suggests "... when he photobombed my picture". Is that correct?

But "photobomb" sounds like she is doing it on purpose. She might do it on purpose or by accident.
